# KotlinのFragmentでQRコードリーダーを開く方法について

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, fragment

初学者でつたない質問で申し訳ありません。
KotlinでFragmentでQRコードリーダーを起動して読み取るにはどうするべきでしょうか？

[【コピペで作る】kotlin QRコード導入手順5ステップ](https://shoheohtani.blogspot.com/2019/01/kotlin-qrcode-how-to.html)
[【Android/Kotlin】ZXing Android Embeddedを用いて簡単にQRコードを扱う](https://blog.beatdjam.com/entry/2019/11/17/195727)

上記の情報とかがHitしたので読みながらどうにか実践しようとしているんですがうまく動かせません。
Activityでは起動できるそうなのですが、どうにかFragment上で動かした結果を取得したいのですが可能でしょうか？

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.qrcode.QRCodeActivity">
    
    <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CompoundBarcodeView
        android:id="@+id/qr_camera"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1.3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
class QRCodeActivity : Fragment(){

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_qr_code, container, false)
        return root
    }

}
```

Comment: 「うまく動かない」をより具体的に説明した方がアドバイスも付きやすいと思います。 / 「QRコードリーダーを作成」と「QRコードリーダーを起動」では意味合いが違ってきますが、どちらでしょうか？

Comment: cubickさん　ご指摘ありがとうございます！  「QRコードリーダーを作成」と「QRコードリーダーを起動」の意味が分かってないのでまずそこから調べてみます。  
xmlに書いてあるCompoundBarcodeViewで作成完了かと思っていました。